# Will bacterial promoter without either -10 or -35 sequence allow no transcription?

Tags: transcription, ecoli, polymerase

I have a strong constitutive promoter on a plasmid inside of E.Coli, which expresses a gene. Having either -10 or -35 sequence modified to random sequence, will it ensure zero transcription from that promoter?

Thanks.